Somehow I'm frying KY002 flipflop module on an LED turn signal flasher circuit

Im using relay 303-1ah-c-r1 4 pin relay ( has a resistor) with KY002S 5amp flipflop module( https://www.ebay.com/itm/154550492996 ). I have 12v car battery into 3 amp fuse, then into ky002s + input, then out the ouput pin of the ky002 module to the relay 86 pin, then the 85 pin to ground. The ky002 module has a ground and a trigger pin. I have the ground to frame of auto, and trigger to the turn signal switch(basically low pulse ground signal to turn flip flop module on/off).
I basically need to turn my signal lights (led) on and off via a low pulse from the handle.  push once, light starts to blink, push again it goes off.
load circuit starts at battery, 15amp fuse, ep29 flasher relay + in, ep29 ground, and the L pin goes to the 30 pin of the 303-1ah-c-r1 relay, and from 303-1ah-c-r1 87 pin to turn signal light.
trigger circuit starts at battery, 2 amp fuse, into the flip flop switch + in, then from flip flop + out to the 86 pin of the 303-1ah-c-r1 relay, then 303-1ah-c-r1 85 pin to ground.
circuit works, but randomly the ky002s chip module will fry...Im not sure why.  its only function is to turn on the 303-1ah-c-r1 relay so that the ep29 flasher relay then gets power.  The ky002s module is rated for 5amps, and I have a 1 amp fuse at battery and the fuse has never blown. I tested the power on the ky002s leads when operating and on the 200m setting I got .2 amps during operation.  10A setting of multimeter reads .02 and 20m setting reads .02
should I get 303-1ah-c-D1 relay with a diode instead?  should I add a diode on to the relay or the circuit?

In an automotive application you should use automotive rated parts.

Also, if there is a comparable but "automotive version" of the ky002s module, please let me know.  I just need a latching relay that is latched and unlatched by a low-pulse electrical signal.  "one push lights turn on, another push lights go off" kinda thing.

@CRPKOKI - Hi, You ask "should I get 303-1ah-c-D1 relay with a diode instead? should I add a diode on to the relay or the circuit?" But your schematic already shows diodes across all 3 relay coils. So it seems that the schematic is not the same as your existing circuit - otherwise you wouldn't be asking about adding diodes. Please clarify. || Also, please explain exactly what you mean by: "randomly the ky002s chip module will fry" Is there visible damage on a component? Or did you mean something else by "fry"? Have you done any analysis e.g. by testing / replacing failed components? TY

Flyback diodes across the relay coils are obviously mandatory (and a FAQ). other than that, on an automotive application, where & how you ground things make a big difference. It's also very fishy design to not have any TVS anywhere.

I would just build the whole thing out of relays. We'll design for grounded active signals. When a signal is grounded, it's active/ON. When it's floating or connected to 12V, it's inactive/OFF.
Newest Solution
RLY1 is an automotive relay. RLY2 is a signal relay. S1 is a 1xform A (SW1a), 1xform B (SW1b) pushbutton: it has one pair of NO contacts (SW1a) and one pair of NC contacts (SW1b).
D1 and D2 are isolation diodes. D3 and D4 are freewheeling (flyback) diodes.

Initially, everything is off.
S1 depressed: S1a closes, S1b opens.
RLY1 turns on, LOAD turns on.
S1 released: S1a opens, S1b closes.
RLY1 is now latched on via D1. RLY2 turns on via D2.
S1 depressed: S1a closes, S1b opens.
RLY1 turns off, LOAD turns off, the state of RLY2 is maintained by S1a.
S1 released: S1a opens, S1b closes.
RLY2 turns off.
Now we're back to state 1.


simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Solution Suggested by G36

simulate this circuit
Here's how it works:

K1 and K2 are off, LOAD is OFF
TOGGLE depressed, K1 energized via TOGGLE.
K1 turns on, K2 is grounded on both sides so doesn't react. LOAD is ON.
TOGGLE released, midpoint between K1 and K2 coils is not grounded anymore. K2 turns on.
LOAD stays ON.
TOGGLE depressed, K2 is fully energized but K1 has 12V on both sides so begins to turn OFF.
K1 turns off, LOAD turns OFF.
TOGGLE released, K2 loses power and turns OFF.
We're back to state 1.

Now we can improve this circuit so that it doesn't depend on the coils operating in series. We start with a double-throw 3-pole pushbutton:

simulate this circuit
Now that relatively expensive pushbutton can be replaced with a relay:

simulate this circuit
When the pushbutton is depressed, K3 energizes the K2 switching circuit. When the pushbutton is released, K3 maintains the memory of the circuit.
In practice, K1a would be a SPST power relay to control the load, and K1b would be a DPST or DPDT signal relay:

simulate this circuit
So, an implementation that runs the relays at full coil voltage needs 4 relays, just like the one below. They just use those relays in different ways.

Original Solution
Let's see how a toggle circuit can be made out of relays. First, let's start with the basic two-button circuit:

simulate this circuit
It works as expected: ON turns the LOAD on, OFF turns the LOAD off. RLY1 is the load control relay and needs to handle the load current. Other relays - RLY2 and up - are signal relays and don't need to handle much current at all.
Now we need to control it with a single button. A relay can select which of the two coils are energized by the single button:

simulate this circuit
Now we "only" need to figure out how to control RLY3. Basically, what we need is for RLY3 to keep its state unchanged while the button is depressed. When the button is released, RLY3 should be free to mirror the state of the load.
For this, we'll use a latch circuit. In the latch below, OUT mirrors the IN state. I.e. if IN is grounded, out is grounded. But when LATCH becomes active, the OUT state is frozen and does not depend on IN anymore.

simulate this circuit
Now we can integrate the two circuits. Observe how RLY3b holds the output state of the latch. That's exactly what we want RLY3a to do. They are the same relay, then!

simulate this circuit
Here's how that works:

All relays are off, load is off.
TOGGLE is pressed: RLY4 and RLY1 turn on. LOAD turns on. RLY4 starts to hold previous state on RLY3 - thus RLY3 stays off.
TOGGLE is released: RLY4 turns off, and allows RLY3 to follow the output state. RLY3 turns on.
TOGGLE is pressed: RLY4 and RLY2 turns on. RLY4 starts to hold previous state on RLY3 - thus RLY3 stays ON.
RLY1 loses power due to RLY2 turning ON. LOAD turns OFF.
TOGGLE is released: RLY2 turns off. RLY4 opens, allowing RLY3 to follow the output state. RLY3 turns off.
All relays are off. We're back to the 1st state now.

RLY1 should be an automotive load relay rated to handle the load current. RLY2..RLY4 can be 12V PCB-mounted relays on a small piece of protoboard. The pushbutton only deals with coil currents so 0.5A rating will be sufficient.
If TOGGLE could be a DPDT momentary switch, it could replace RLY4:

simulate this circuit

We can use two relays to get toggle function. https://elportal.pl/czytelnia/konkursy/703-jak-to-dziala-elektromechaniczny-przerzutnik-toggle-przerzutnik-t  But the relays need to be able to energize at 0.5Vsup. Which is not a problem. I tested this circuit in a real world.

@G36 It is a great circuit as long as the relays are OK with half the supply voltage. Most are when you run the supply at the rated voltage. But if you were running a lower supply to reduce thermal output - say in a relay computer (my application, there's thousands of relays in a small volume), then it becomes unreliable. I tried. But that's a really rare application, I know.

We could try to add pull-up resistor in parallel with K1.
